# v-validation with dynamic component

Tags: vue.js

I'm a new in vuejs and i want to add validation in dynamic component.
 
My code like this:

```html
<div class="widget-main  padding-6" v-for="serving in servingData">
<div class="form-group col-sm-5">
    <label for="form-field-unit">@lang('master_foods.unit')</label>
    <input name="unit" class="input-sm form-control" id="form-field-unit"  v-model="serving.unit" tabindex="23@{{$index}}" type="text" placeholder="Unit" v-validate:unit="rules.unit" required>
    <span v-cloak v-if="$master_food.unit.touched && $master_food.unit.invalid" class="text-danger">
        <div class="space-2"></div>                                 
        <div v-for="error in $master_food.unit.errors">
            <i class="ace-icon fa fa-circle red"></i>&nbsp;@{{ error.message }}
        </div>
    </span>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-sm-2" >
    <button tabindex="-1" class="btn btn-sm btn-grey" type="button" style="margin-top: 23px;" @click="removeServingData(serving)" v-if="$index>0">
        <i class="ace-icon fa fa-trash-o bigger-110"></i>
        Remove
    </button>
</div>
```

When i click on "ADD MORE" button then i have push one record in side servingData array and each field has remove button for remove this filed. so if user has add "N" number of component then i want to validate each and every component. currently validation working only for last one component so how can i solve this issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**@test** you can  use **:field** attribute for dynamic validate. Bellow I have add some sample code

```html
<div class="widget-main  padding-6" v-for="serving in servingData">
<div class="form-group col-sm-5">
    <label for="form-field-unit">@lang('master_foods.unit')</label>
    <input name="unit" class="input-sm form-control" id="form-field-unit"  v-model="serving.unit" tabindex="23@{{$index}}" type="text" placeholder="Unit" :field="'unit' + serving.servingId" v-validate="rules.unit" required>
    <span v-cloak v-if="$master_food['unit' + serving.servingId].touched && $master_food['unit' + serving.servingId].invalid" class="text-danger">
        <div class="space-2"></div>                                 
        <div v-for="error in $master_food['unit' + serving.servingId].errors">
            <i class="ace-icon fa fa-circle red"></i>&nbsp;@{{ error.message }}
        </div>
    </span>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-sm-2" >
    <button tabindex="-1" class="btn btn-sm btn-grey" type="button" style="margin-top: 23px;" @click="removeServingData(serving)" v-if="$index>0">
        <i class="ace-icon fa fa-trash-o bigger-110"></i>
        Remove
    </button>
</div>
```

I have assume servingId for differentiate particular record.FYI:You don't use $index for differentiate the array record because it's changeable when we remove or add record